# Nginx virtual host with a subdirectory with rewrites

Tags: nginx

I have a Debian 12 + Nginx 1.22 + PHP 8 server with the following files structure:

```
/home/www/
└───example
    └───mysubwebsite
```

The corresponding nginx vhost conf file for "example" is:

```
server {

    server_name example.com;

    root /home/www/example;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /mysubwebsite {
        rewrite ^/mysubwebsite/(.*)\.html$    /mysubwebsite/index.php?hash=$1 last;
    }

}
```

It works fine, mysubwesite can be accessed on `http://example.com/mysubwebsite`, with the proper rewrites.

Now I need to move mysubwebsite folder on my server to the parent folder, while keeping the same public URLs and rewrite rule for mysubwebsite:

```
/home/www/
├───example
└───mysubwebsite
```

So I updated the vhost conf file that way:

```
server {

    server_name example.com;

    root /home/www/example;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /mysubwebsite {
        root /home/www;
        rewrite ^/mysubwebsite/(.*)\.html$    index.php?hash=$1 last;
    }

}
```

But I get 404 when browsing to `http://example.com/mysubwebsite`, with no logs. I also tried different paths for the rewrite directive, with no success.

**What is the correct way to configure the rewrites of the subdirectory for this case?**

EDIT: added to the examples the PHP processing directives for the domain which I didn't mention at first, didn't realise it was significant

Comment: Show full server block. This one obviously missing location with PHP processing

Comment: Indeed, it was because of the PHP preprocessing missing in the location directive. Not that obvious. Shall I post an answer or do you want to do it?